# WooThemes Projects plugin - Change the location of a displayed costum field

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using [Woocommerce Projects plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/projects/) for WooCommerce and I have made some extra meta fields for the Projects.

But how can I display them on the place where I want them?

On this [example page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-project-meta-field/) they show an option that will show it under the short description. But how can I change the location, to put it everywhere I want in the template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update** *(see below: Overriding Projects template files safely)*

What you are looking at, is [**this documentation**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hook-filter-reference/), that lists all possible hooks with [WooCommerce "Projects" plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/projects/).

So you will have just change the hook in:

```
add_action( 'projects_after_loop_item', 'display_new_projects_fields', 10 );
```

Replacing  **`'projects_after_loop_item'`** by one of the hooks below to change the displayed location around the loop (for example):

```
projects_before_loop
projects_before_loop_item
projects_loop_item
projects_after_loop_item
projects_after_loop
```

Or also *(with the other  "Projects" plugin templates)*:

```
## General layout
projects_before_main_content
projects_after_main_content
projects_sidebar

## Archives
projects_archive_description

## Single Projects
projects_before_single_project
projects_before_single_project_summary
projects_single_project_summary
projects_after_single_project_summary
projects_after_single_project
```

---

**Overriding Projects template files safely**

> **Copy** the **`templates`** directory located in  **`projects-by-woothemes`** plugin folder to your active child theme directory *(or active theme directory)* and rename it **`projects`**.

*Projects plugin will always check your theme for these files before displaying core templates as a fallback. Any template files found in the theme will be given priority and the core counterpart ignored.*

> **Now you can edit any template file as you want**, adding inside it this little peace of code (from the example), **directly just where you want**, displaying your custom field value, just using:

```
echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_location', true ) );
```

At the end, is better to keep in that folder, only the customized templates.

---

Reference and related:

- [Editing Projects Templates Safely](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-projects-templates-safely/)
- [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: But it is not possible to do it like: <?php projects_get_template_part( 'title', 'project' ); ?> so i can put the title in a heading? (i am not a PHP guy but i am learning) haha :p

Comment: I am using ACF also for the website but because i am just new into PHP (i am a designer not a PHP programmer) i was thinking it's to hard for me to make it the same as this plugin. I need the categorys and that people can easy add more categorys or edit them. And that you can visit a category page and stuff like that.

Comment: that is working! I was already creating a own template inside my theme folder so that i was doing good already. But now i am wondering how i can display only the category where the product is in. Do you know that how i can show that? And then i know everything :-)